# Parameters for delegatecall in inline assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am trying to perform a delegate call from inline-assembly and I am unable to wrap my head around how to access the memory variables assigned outside the assembly block.

```
function() external payable {
  bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature("modValue(uint256)", 25);
  address _delegate = delegate;
  assembly {
    let result := delegatecall(gas, _delegate, [#1], [#2], 0, 0)
  }
}
```

If I want to send the **data** variable as the calldata, then what should be the values in place for **[#1]** and **[#2]**? The size of **data** is 36 bytes here, so **[#2]** = 36? How can we access the memory location for externally defined variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 32 bytes of a bytes array are the length and the rest is the data.

- To calculate a pointer to an array's data in assembly it will be `add(array, 32)`.
- To read the array's length it will be `mload(array)`.

Combining them together it should be

```
assembly {
    let result := delegatecall(gas, _delegate, add(data, 32), mload(data), 0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, to access variables check the [official docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/assembly.html#access-to-external-variables-functions-and-libraries):

> For local storage variables or state variables, a single Yul
> identifier is not sufficient, since they do not necessarily occupy a
> single full storage slot. Therefore, their “address” is composed of a
> slot and a byte-offset inside that slot. To retrieve the slot pointed
> to by the variable `x`, you use `x.slot`, and to retrieve the byte-offset
> you use `x.offset`. Using `x` itself will result in an error.

To illustrate the example I will use the latest Solidity version (`v0.7.4`).

In order to facilitate the explanation I will change your function. Suppose you have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

contract D {
    function modValue(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return a % b;
    }
}
```

Suppose we create another contract in order to perform a `delegatecall`. We have the `_delegate` variable which is initialized in the constructor. As you can see, this variable is outside the assembly block. Thus, we need to add `.slot` to get the variable value inside the assembly block using the `sload` opcode.

*The first 32 bytes of `data` indicate its length, that's why we do `add(data,32)` to get the `data` value. In addition, to get the `data` length you should use the `mload` opcode. More info about opcodes [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yul.html#evm-dialect).*

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

contract StackExchange {
    
    address _delegate;
    
    constructor (address delegate) {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }
    
    function getValue() public returns (uint256) {
        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature("modValue(uint256,uint256)", 52, 3);

        assembly {
            let pointer := mload(0x40)
            
            if iszero(delegatecall(not(0), sload(_delegate.slot), add(data,32), mload(data), pointer, 0x20)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }

            let size := returndatasize()
            returndatacopy(pointer, 0, size)
            return(pointer,size)
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to test the contracts in Remix.